# javascript how can i run 2 file reader methods(readAsArrayBuffer() & readAsDataURL())?

Tags: javascript

i currently have the ff code my goal is to remove the extra filreader loop? is it possible to maybe chain the readAsArrayBuffer and readAsDataURL or load them both?

```
var images = [];
var files = dt.files.length;
for (i = 0; i < files; i++) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.fileId = i;
reader.onload = function (){
    images[this.fileId].is_valid = true / false; // checks mime type
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(dt.files[i]);

for (i = 0; i < files; i++) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.fileId = i;
reader.onload = function (){
    //load image
    if(image[i].is_valid){ 
    // do this
   }else {
    // do this
   }
}

reader.readAsDataURL(dt.files[i]);
```